# Hiding Apache Camel servlet behind Spring MVC Controller entry point

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, apache-camel

I want to hide the [Apache Camel Servlet](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html) behind Spring MVC Controller entry point, because I have some proprietary components I have to use that depend on Sping Boot and Spring MVC Controller.

I have the following Apache Camel Route, which is working fine

```
<route id="Route">
            <from uri="servlet:messages?httpMethodRestrict=POST"/>
            <process ref="..."></process>
            <to uri="{{storage.service.endpoint}}?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
</route>
```

I have registered the Camel Servlet [without any URL mappings](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2596), because I don't want to be accessible directly. The Spring Bean:

```
@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
      CamelHttpTransportServlet camelServlet = new CamelHttpTransportServlet();
      ServletRegistrationBean servletBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(camelServlet, false, new String[]{});
      servletBean.setName("CamelServlet");
      return servletBean;
}
```

In Spring Controller Entry point I just need to forward to Camel Servlet:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/api/v1/*")
public void wrapper(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
      context.getNamedDispatcher("CamelServlet").forward(request, response);
}
```

**The problem** is that Camel Servlet relies on ServletResolveConsumerStrategy using `request.getPathInfo()`, which is always `null` in Spring Controller entry point. I have tried different paths in `@RequestMapping`, but always `request.getServletPath()` has the full path and the `pathInfo` is null

P.S. The application is running on Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the  Spring Controller entry point using path variables and set the value of the path variable a `pathInfo()` in a custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper`:

```
  @RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/{messages}" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public void wrapper2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String messages) throws Exception{
      request = new PathInfoRequestWrapper(request, messages);
      context.getNamedDispatcher("CamelServlet").forward(request, response);

  }

  class PathInfoRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{
    private String pathInfo;

    public PathInfoRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String pathInfo) {
       super(request);
       this.pathInfo = pathInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPathInfo(){
        String origPathInfo = super.getPathInfo();
        if(origPathInfo == null || origPathInfo.equals("")){
            return this.pathInfo;
        }else{
            return origPathInfo;
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create custom `ServletResolveConsumerStrategy`, which relies only on `request.getServletPath()`, to find the appropriate route. Unfortunately only setting the Strategy with `org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.setServletResolveConsumerStrategy(ServletResolveConsumerStrategy)` does not work, because the it is overwritten in org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet.init method. SO you need to override the init in the Camel Servlet as well:

```
CamelHttpTransportServlet camelServlet = new CamelHttpTransportServlet(){
          @Override
          public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
              super.init(config);
              ServletResolveConsumerStrategy servletResolveConsumerStrategy = new CamelSpringResolveConsumerStrategy();
              setServletResolveConsumerStrategy(servletResolveConsumerStrategy );
          }
      };
```